# jQuery .click function executes twice in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick, alert

I'm working on my first program using jQuery, but I'm having an issue.  I have a dialog pop up on pageLoad that asks the user to select a date and a turn.  Right now, for debugging purposes, I have it alert every time .click() executes, and for some reason, it seems like it executes *before* the user clicks and immediately afterward.

There are three radio buttons, Turns 1, 2, and 3.  When the user clicks Turn 1, the alert should say "1".  When the user clicks Turn 2, the alert should say "2", etc.  But for some reason, it alerts the previous value as well as the new one. I searched all of my code, and there is only one alert, so I can't figure out what is calling click() twice.  I've tested it in IE and Chrome and it happened both times.

This is my .click() function:

```
$("#turn-radio")
    .click(function () {
    turnvalue = $("input[name='turn-radio']:checked").val();
    alert(turnvalue);
});
```

If you check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZYPL5/1/), you'll see the rest of my code, which will hopefully make it easier to figure out what my problem is.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `selector:` as your radio button IDs are different and you were giving name as a `selector` that's why you were facing that problem:

```
 $("input[name='turn-radio']")
        .click(function () {
        turnvalue = $("input[name='turn-radio']:checked").val();
        alert(turnvalue);
    });
```

#### Updated Fiddle

Comment: That totally did it!  Thanks so much. :)

Answer (score 1):

changing

```
$("#turn-radio") to $("#turn-radio label")
```

causes only one popup displaying the previous value

But, personally i would

```
$("#turn-radio input").change( function() { /* do stuff */ } )
```

Comment: Excellent.  Can you explain _why_ it does that?

Comment: because the click event propagates off of the innermost element, which in your code is two overlayed elements, a label and a radio input. you get a click event called from two child elements that both get clicked. :)

Comment: Agh, so it was the label that was causing a second .click() execution?  That makes sense.  I don't know what inspired me to give them the same name. My label won't be changing anyway, so it doesn't even need a name

Comment: overkill is never a bad thing, as long as each part of the process is exactly specific to the needs. Another bug that could have been introduced is that the popup would be displayed wherever you clicked within the container div instead of, as I'm assuming you wanted, on the click that changes the input. Glad I could be of help! Anything else you're needing?

Comment: wow, that's great.  Thanks so much for the help.  I actually am having another related issue, but I'll form a new question for it and post the link here

Comment: Here's a link to my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599187/cant-get-my-jquery-dialog-to-open-on-menu-item-click