# Can't get my jQuery dialog to open on menu item click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've got my first app with jQuery coming along, and I've got both my dialog boxes built and executing as they should be, and the login box comes up when I click login (in the File menu), but I can't get the Open box to come up when I click Open.

Here's my jQuery code for both dialogs:

```
$("#login-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 350,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Log In": function () {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(username, "username", 3, 16);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);

            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(username, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, begin with a letter.");
            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password may consist of : a-z 0-9");

            if (bValid) {
                if (username.val() == "admin" && password.val() == "password") {
                    $("#users tbody").append("<tr>" + "<td>" + username.val() + "</td>" + "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" + "</tr>");
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                } else {
                    alert("Invalid Username/Password Combo");
                }
            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

$("#dateturn-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 550,
    width: 350,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Accept": function () {
            $("#content-left").append("<p>Date: " + dateinput.val() + " turn: " + turnvalue + "</p>");
            $(this).dialog("close");


        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    }
});

$("#login")
    .click(function () {
    $("#login-form").dialog("open");
});

$("#open")
    .click(function () {
    $("dateturn-form").dialog("open");
});
```

And here's a jsFiddle link to the project: http://jsfiddle.net/CHBrn/1/   For some reason, like I said above, clicking the Open button won't launch the project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once again Alex :) You are missing `#` in ID selector

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CHBrn/1/)

```
$("#dateturn-form").dialog({ });
```

Comment: Hahahaha, thank you for pointing that out.  And yes, once again me, haha.  This is my first experience with jQuery, and I learn a lot better by being taught than by reading guides.  

Of course, don't get me wrong, i'm definitely going through documentation as I do stuff, but stupid mistakes like this aren't going to come up in the API documentation, haha. 

thanks. :)

Comment: hahaha... No worries, Man learns from the mistakes.. :) Cheers!! Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you so much!  This is absolutely happy coding.  I've had friends tell me about the wonders of jQuery before, but I always wrote it off as too much work to use, but now I'm blown away.  I've learned so much in the past two days of using it.

Answer (score 4):

You are missing a hash (`#`).

Replace

```
$("dateturn-form").dialog("open");
```

with

```
$("#dateturn-form").dialog("open");
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CHBrn/2/)

Comment: Oh god.  Thank you.  I feel so dumb for this.

Comment: @AlexKibler, we've all made that kind of mistake. You shouldn't feel dumb about it.  I remember once I spent three days trying to fix a bug and got everyone in the office involved, and we had all missed the small typo that was causing the problem. ;)

Comment: Haha, that sounds like quite a problem.  I used to do that all the time with colons and semicolons when I was taking c++ classes in college.